# Asymptotic solution

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I have an ODE

```
V''[z] + ( (I z0^2 w)/(3 (z - z0)^2) + (2 - (4 I z0 w)/9)/(z - z0)) V'[z] + 
 (-(12/41) I z0 w + (23 z0^2 w^2)/369)/(z - z0)^2 V[z] == 0
```

*Mathematica* can solve this exactly. But I just need the asymptotic behavior of the solution near `z = z0`. I have tried `Series` near `z = z0`, but the solution still looks messy. Is there any way to directly obtain the asymptotic behavior in *Mathematica*?

Comment: By "directly" do you mean plotting the variable v and observing asymptotic behaviour at `z=z0`. What is this equation modeling? What are some usual boundary conditions that may be applied to resolve constants of integration? These details may help further.

Comment: I think the question I am asking is very simple one. Even if I expand any one of those two solutions up to 0-th order in `z - z0`  I get a complicated looking expression. I want to have only the leading (and/or sub-leading) singular behavior. I just wanted to know if there is any way to extract that from the original ODE.

Comment: Could you, in your question, also include the expansion? Did you use `DSolveValue` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution:

```
ex = DSolveValue[
 V''[z] + ((I z0^2 w)/(3 (z - z0)^2) + (2 - (4 I z0 w)/9)/(z - 
         z0)) V'[
     z] + (-(12/41) I z0 w + (23 z0^2 w^2)/369)/(z - z0)^2 V[z] ==
   0, V[z], z] /. C[1] -> 1 /. C[2] -> 1 // Simplify
```

involves some `Hypergeometric1F1` functions. (Note that we set the two free constants `C[1]=C[2]=1` for simplicity here. Set them as you need for your boundary conditions later.)

Trying to expand `ex` around `z=z0` causes some messy `Floor` functions to appear, because Mathematica is careful about the symbolic parameters potentially being complex. Instead of using Mathematica, we can just look up the expansion - see the last equation [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/06/02/):

$$\, _1F_1(a;b;z)\propto \frac{e^z \Gamma (b)
   \left(O\left(\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^1\right)+1\right) z^{a-b}}{\Gamma (a)}+\frac{(-z)^{-a}
   \Gamma (b) \left(O\left(\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^1\right)+1\right)}{\Gamma
   (b-a)}$$

Which is valid for $\left| z\right| \to \infty $. Dropping the $O\left(\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^1\right)$ terms we get:

```
ex2 = ex /.Hypergeometric1F1[a_, b_, c_] ->Gamma[b]/Gamma[b - a] (-c)^-a+Gamma[b]/Gamma[a] Exp[c] c^(a - b);
```

This new expression `ex2` now features only rational functions in `z-z0` to some powers dependent on the parameters `w,z0` and constant factors dependent of the same parameters.

One can also check for some particular values of parameters (i.e. `w=Pi`, `z0=1`) that the asymptotics works correctly. Real part of the ratio of full solution and approximation properly goes to $1$ around `z=z0=1`:

```
Plot[{1, Re[ex/ex2]} /. w -> \[Pi] /. z0 -> 1, {z, 0, 2}]
```

> [image]

and imaginary part of the ratio properly vanishes there:

```
Plot[{1, Im[ex/ex2]} /. w -> \[Pi] /. z0 -> 1, {z, 0, 2}]
```

> [image]